# Looking for MacBook pro SSD schematic documents

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, data-recovery

A MacBook pro SSD is not recognized by the machine (SanDisk). Possibly some embedded circuit failure or component damage. I searched for the schematic diagram to perform voltage checking and soldering, but nowhere found. Any help or recommendation would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you've just bought it, return it. Not worth the effort.

Comment: You're not going to 'solder' an SSD with anything you have in a DIY kit.

Comment: @Andy:There are some important notes and academic files in it.

Comment: @Tetsujin:If the schematic is available, I can take it to my university lab for testing.